# JTable cloumn doesn't get focused anymore

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Recently I have a small problem with one column in a JTable: since I edited it's DefaultTableCellRenderer the password column doesn't get focused, when I focus a row in the table. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt43z.png) an my code:

```
inputsTable.getColumn("Passwort").setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){

        private final String ASTERISKS = "*";
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                       Object value,
                                                       boolean isSelected,
                                                       boolean hasFocus,
                                                       int row,
                                                       int column) {
            int length =0;
            if (value instanceof String) {
                length =  ((String) value).length();
            } else if (value instanceof char[]) {
                length = ((char[])value).length;
            }
            setText(asterisks(length));
            return this;
        }
        private String asterisks(int length) {
            if (length > ASTERISKS.length()) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    sb.append('*');
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } else {
                return ASTERISKS.substring(0, length);
            }
        }
    });
```

I have already tried some different options, but they didn't help me, unfortunately. Does anyone of you have eventually a clue, is there maybe some better implementation of a password column in a JTable without this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultTableCellRenderer` implementation posted sets no formatting based upon the current state (in particular the `isSelected` parameter). To keep default formatting, consider calling the parent method prior to your customization.

```
                public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                               Object value,
                                                               boolean isSelected,
                                                               boolean hasFocus,
                                                               int row,
                                                               int column) {
                    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
                    //do your customization here
                }
```